# How do I rename files with spaces using the Linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I named a number of files with spaces in them, and I want to replace the space with `_`. However, every time I write a command in the shell with the file name (eg `Spring 2011`), the shell doesn't recognize the file or directory.

What can I do about this? Is there any way to use the unicode character for a space?

Comment: for programmatically renaming N files, use a `bash` for loop: [see my solution here](https://superuser.com/a/1363658/28756).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Escape the space, e.g. `Spring\ 2011`, or use quotes, e.g. `'Spring 2011'`. In the future, it's typically a bad idea to use file names with spaces in them on any *NIX.

If you've got `rename`, you can use this:

```
rename ' ' '_' [filenames...]
```

Comment: Do you know is there anyway to do this for all the files at once?

Comment: @phil for the rename command, specify a pattern for filenames that matches all the files you want to rename (e.g. if there's a common prefix/suffix).

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? It's the responsibility of the programmer to handle filenames properly.

Comment: @glenn because spaces in a filename have to be either escaped or quoted in the shell, which is extra effort for anyone writing scripts and can be error prone.

Comment: @rafe, really it's error prone not to handle filenames properly up front. The extra effort comes when having to debug a script when you simply forgot to quote variables containing a filename.

Comment: This answer does not seem to work (on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, at least). The answer from _unutbu_ works fine though.

Comment: Didn't work for me (Ubuntu/LinuxMint). 

This did work: rename "s/\s/_/g" [filenames...]

Comment: for programmatically renaming N files, use a `bash` for loop: [see my solution here](https://superuser.com/a/1363658/28756).

Comment: this only did the first space for me... which is not helpful (i have `rename` version 2.23)

Comment: which `rename`? There's more than one. Please specify

Comment: It's a bad idea because it makes life more difficult for any **users** who use the command line.  They do exist.

Answer (score 39):

If you don't have `rename` or prefer to use just the shell:

```
for f in *\ *; do mv "$f" "${f// /_}"; done
```

Broken down:

- `*\ *` selects all files with a space in their name as input for the the `for` loop.  The pattern `*X*` selects all files with `X` in their name, and for the special character space, we have to escape it with a slash so that bash doesn't treat it as separating different arguments.
- The quotes around `"$f"` are important because we know there's a space in the filename and otherwise it would appear as 2+ arguments to `mv`.
- `${f//str/new_str}` is a bash-specific string substitution feature.  All instances of `str` are replaced with `new_str`.

Comment: this works but for me it only replaces the first space.  if i use `for f in *\ *; do mv "$f" "${f// /_}"; done` it works

Comment: @billynoah Good catch, updated.

Comment: @blahdiblah Thank you so much!  You just saved me so much time!

Comment: @blahdiblah your solution is way way more elegant than [my solution](https://superuser.com/a/1363658/28756). good job. I didn't think the for loop glob would work... so i did the glob outside of the for loop.

Comment: That was so quick and easy, and the bash is semi-understandable. How does the `*\ *` work to select all files?

Comment: @BrianPeterson The shell uses globbing (which is different from regexp, BTW, see https://www.malikbrowne.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-glob-patterns/ for a good introduction). The first  matches `*`  any non-slash characters before the space, the `\ ` matches the space and the second `*` matches any non-slash characters after the space. If you wanted to restrict the renaming to only pdfs, you'd use `*\ *.pdf`

Answer (score 36):

If your machine has the [rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) command, then this will change all spaces to underscores in all files/dirs in the current working directory:

```
rename 's/ /_/g' *
```

Comment: Confirmed to work in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: didn't work for me... i got an error of "rename: not enough arguments". i have version `rename --version` `rename from util-linux 2.23.2`.

Comment: `-bash: /usr/bin/rename: Argument list too long`

Comment: There are two main rename utilities. "rename from util-linux" and "perl-rename". The one from util-linux doesn't support regular expressions. You may need to explicitly install the perl one to do regular expressions depending on your distro.

Answer (score 6):

`mv "Spring 2011.file" Spring_2011.file` should tell the command-line to take the quoted string as a single input.

Answer (score 2):

**To programmatically rename N files, you can use a simple `bash` for loop.**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eux

# find all your files by using a `grep` pattern
pattern="insert_filename_pattern_here" # you must enter your filename pattern here

# create an array of filenames and split on newlines
IFS=$'\n'
tmp=($(ls | grep ${pattern}))
unset IFS

# for each filename
for filename in "${tmp[@]}"; do
    # rename the filename to use "_" character instead of a " " character
    mv -v "${filename}" "${filename// /_}"
done
```

**If you have less than 5 filenames, then you can manually type in all the filenames and use the `rename` command like the above [solution](https://superuser.com/a/295995/28756) suggests.** But for me... I prefer the programmatic solution... even when there is only 4 files.

p.s.

if you aren't familiar with `Bash`'s Parameter Expansion (i.e. `${filename// /_}`) you could use the `rename` command:

```
if ((0)); then
    mv -v "${filename}" "${filename// /_}"
else
    rename ' ' '_' "${filename}"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the command 'detox' it has useful options like dry run, recursive, can be called on a single file, directory, or an entire filesystem if you wish

Comment: Amazing function, very easy to use. Thanks!