# How to batch rename files by removing special character without using rename in linux shell

Tags: bash, mv

For example, I have 100 files and their names all have blank space. One of them is "`The Monkey King Return (2015).mkv`".

How to remove all blank in name and replace with dot character, also remove "("  and ")"?

The result should be "`The.Monkey.King.Return.2015.mkv`".

how I can do this in batch?

I am actually running shell script in my Synology NAS via ssh, which is a BusyBox Linux distribution with bash and ash installed, without gcc. Already tried for serveral days, cannot figure it out properly.

**Tools aviable: mv / xargs / sed / awk / other standard linux cmd.**

Also how about recursively do the renaming for sub folders as well?

Edit: just installed apt-get and rename cmd into my synology nas by using Debian Chroot from https://synocommunity.com/, so it is ok now.

To make person who need simple answer, the cmd is:

```
find . -iname \*\ \*.\*|rename 's/\ /\./g'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I rename files with spaces using the Linux shell?](http://superuser.com/questions/295994/how-do-i-rename-files-with-spaces-using-the-linux-shell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most linux distro's include [util-linux](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/) which gives you the `rename` command. You can do what you request by running these commands:

```
rename ' ' _ *.mkv
rename '(20' 20 *.mkv
rename ').' . *.mkv
```

You can experiment with the options, it's pretty flexible. If you want to do this recursively, combine `rename` with the find command like this:

```
find . -type f -name \*.mkv -exec rename ' ' _ {} \;
```

These are explained in the manual; type `man find` or `man rename` to read them.

---

Beware that some distro's apparently include a different command which accepts perl regular expressions. If yours does too, you'll need a slightly different syntax:

```
rename 's/\ /./g' *.mkv
rename 's/[\)\(]//g' *.mkv
```

Comment: Beware! At least if yours is the same as mine, `rename` takes a regular expression, and in a regular expression, `.` matches *any* single character.

Comment: Well, mine doesn't and the man-page confirms it by supplying this example: `rename .htm .html *.htm`. But I'll append the warning, thanks

Comment: I am actually running shell script in my Synology NAS via ssh, which unfortunately does not have 'rename' command, is it possible to do this using mv command?

Comment: @chenyi1976 do you have bash installed? List your constraints in your question

Comment: Ticket updated, it is a BusyBox Linux distribution with bash and ash, without gcc.

Comment: @Sjon one thing I find out is some system like synology is actually using syntax of sed: "rename 's/\ /\./g'  *.mkv"

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have the `rename` command, you can do this with a little shell scripting which busybox's `ash` also seems to support (this is recursive):

```
find -type f -name \*.mkv | while read f; do
    n=${f/ /_} # replace spaces
    n=${n/(/}  # remove opening bracket
    n=${n/)/}  # remove closing bracket

    mv -v "$f" "$n"
done
```

Please note that will break if the folder-names also contain spaces or brackets.

Answer (score 4):

I use this one-liner to remove invalid characters in subtitle files:

```
for f in *.srt; do nf=$(echo "$f" |sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9.-]/./g;s/\.\.\././g;s/\.\././g'); test "$f" != "$nf" && mv "$f" "$nf" && echo "$nf"; done
```

1. Only process *.srt files( * could be used in place of *.srt to process every file)
2. Removes all other characters except for letters A-Za-z, numbers 0-9, periods ".", and dash's "-"
3. Removes possible double or triple periods
4. Checks to see if the file name needs changing
5. If true, it renames the file with the mv command, then outputs the changes it made with the echo command

It works to normalize directory names of movies:

```
for f in */; do nf=$(echo "$f" |sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9.]/./g' -e 's/\.\.\././g' -e 's/\.\././g' -e 's/\.*$//'); test "$f" != "$nf" && mv "$f" "$nf" && echo "$nf"; done
```

Same steps as above but I added one more sed command to remove a period at the end of the directory

X-Men Days of Future Past (2014) [1080p]
Modified to:
X-Men.Days.of.Future.Past.2014.1080p

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking for a solution to this problem for a while now. I work on old closed systems that can't have new packages installed. I don't have the `rename` command. Finally I wrote a script that appears to work with all keyboard entered special characters: `~@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\|;:",<.>?'`

The script will rename every file and directory in the current directory. It will replace all special characters except `-_.` with the `_` character. The `outfile=` line can be modified to use a different character for replacement if desired. Replace `|_|` with `|.|` to use the `.` character for example.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./*
do
  infile=`echo "${file:2}"|sed  \
         -e 's|"\"|"\\"|g' \
         -e 's| |\ |g' -e 's|!|\!|g' \
         -e 's|@|\@|g' -e 's|*|\*|g' \
         -e 's|&|\&|g' -e 's|]|\]|g' \
         -e 's|}|\}|g' -e 's|"|\"|g' \
         -e 's|,|\,|g' -e 's|?|\?|g' \
         -e 's|=|\=|g'  `
  outfile=`echo "${file:2}"|sed -e 's|[^A-Za-z0-9._-]|_|g'`
  mv "$infile" ${outfile} &
done

exit
```